# perform and store various aggregates in one rdd

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have data like so:

```
[('a',110),
 ('a',130),
 ('a',120),
 ('b',200),
 ('b',206)]
```

I want to perform group the keys and perform a **count, average, minimum and maximum** of the values to get the following:

```
[('a', 3, 120, 110, 130),
 ('b', 2, 203, 200, 206)]
```

I roughly know how to do each of the aggregates by itself using countByKey() and reduceByKey() but I'm not sure how to contain it all in the one RDD. Any help?

**edit**: this is a snippet of my real rdd

```
Out[16]: [('Alaska Airlines Inc.', 17.0),
 ('Alaska Airlines Inc.', 63.0),
 ('Alaska Airlines Inc.', 70.0),
 ('Alaska Airlines Inc.', 17.0),
 ('Alaska Airlines Inc.', 16.0),
 ('United Airlines', 9.0),
 ('United Airlines', 197.0),
 ('United Airlines', 115.0),
 ('United Airlines', 6.0),
 ('United Airlines', 1.0),
```

Comment: Must be in RDD?

Comment: @Kafels yep, I want to solve it in RDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to get your solution by using `aggregateByKey` function and `map` to return the desired "schema":

```py
data = sc.parallelize([('a', 110), ('a', 120), ('a', 130), ('b', 200), ('b', 206)])


def sequence_operator(accumulator, element):
  return (accumulator[0] + 1,
         accumulator[1] + element, 
         min(accumulator[2], element),
         max(accumulator[3], element))


def combination_operator(current_accumulator, next_accumulator):
  return (current_accumulator[0] + next_accumulator[0],
         current_accumulator[1] + next_accumulator[1], 
         min(current_accumulator[2], next_accumulator[2]),
         max(current_accumulator[3], next_accumulator[3]))


def unpack_aggregations(data):
  key = data[0]
  count, total, minimum, maximum = data[1]
  return key, count, total / count, minimum, maximum


aggregations = data.aggregateByKey(zeroValue=(0, 0, float('inf'), float('-inf')), seqFunc=sequence_operator, combFunc=combination_operator)
mapped_data = aggregations.map(unpack_aggregations)
print(mapped_data.collect())
```

Output

```py
[('a', 3, 120.0, 110, 130), ('b', 2, 203.0, 200, 206)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried running it on my original rdd and got the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: int; and tuple, line 15. Which is `return key, count, total/count, minimum, maximum`. I'm using Python 3.7.5 environment

Comment: Could you share a small example of your original rdd? Also, what is your spark version? This error is happening because on your data this line `total / count` to get average, one of these values is a tuple for a unknown reason

Comment: I've just added my original rdd to the post, and I'm using Spark 3.0.1

Comment: Being honest I don't know why in your case it's throwing an error. I'll share my [notebook](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2012413774589224/3061277014007120/476673152156399/latest.html) for you take a look. I added my rdd outputs, check if your rdd has the same structure after aggregation

Comment: No worries, thank you so much. Aside from the last `map()`, when I run `aggregations.collect()` on my original rdd, it returns a really weird looking output which looks like a bunch of nested lists, I'll share your [notebook](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/4423643379507875/4267551469955837/2504014137290315/latest.html) when I used the original rdd.

Comment: I have an idea. Apply to your `joinedRDD` the `partitionBy` function selecting the first value before executing the aggregation. It might solve.

Comment: do you mean adding `join_rdd.partitionBy()` before `aggregateByKey`? what number of partitions should I use and how would that affect the aggregation?

Comment: I'm supposing your joinedRDD doesn't has the company as partition key under the hoods and it would break my logic. Tomorrow I'll make some tests and update my answer, it's already midnight here

Comment: @JennyChar I was making  a mistake about `sequence_operator` and `combination_ operator` functions. The `sequence_operator` is where I must create my accumulator and `combination_operator` is where it must merge a previous accumulator with next. Check it again